# How do i set the proper width when fancybox opens an external blueprint styled page?

Tags: fancybox, blueprint-css

I'm styling a ruby-on-rails app and I've got a link to an external page which opens in fancybox.

The external page is styled with blueprint's 24 column width (950px wide).
I've hidden the wide elements (display:none in css) from that page so that the elements I'm interested in are only 250px wide in fancybox.

But when it opens in fancybox it somehow still seems to read the .span-24 attribute rather than opening at the smaller size.

I can't create another external page and must use the blueprint styled one. Any advice on how to force fancybox to open, centered, as a 250px wide box?

Edit:

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("a#fancypants-1").fancybox({
        'autodimensions'    : true,
        'width'             : 250,
        'scrolling'         : 'no',
        'opacity'          : true,
        'overlayShow'       : true,
        'overlayColor'      : '#000',
        'overlayOpacity'    : 0.8,
        'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
        'hideOnContentClick': false ,
        'transitionOut'     : 'none'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

$.fancybox({

```
                    'autoDimensions'  : true,
                'height': 'auto',
                            'width':250px; 
                'scrolling' : 'no',
                'transitionIn'    : 'none',
                'transitionOut'    : 'none',                    

            });
```

Comment: Cheers @mahesh but it's still not working . I'm not sure that fancybox accepts **250px**. From what i understand from the documentation it should just be **250** and there's no mention of it accepting **auto** but it might. I've tried with those amendments as well but no luck, alas. Anything else i might try?